# added header in C, #include returns error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header-files

I added a header in NetBeans 8.0.1 in my project.
But when I include it in a source file I get an error

```
test.c:12:24: fatal error: tester.h: No such file or directory
```

my folder where I save my project is c:\david\temp files\netbeansProjects

could it be because i have a folder name with a space "temp files"? If so how can I change
where all my projects are, without ruining everything.
If that is not the reason, does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: Show your compilation command (and compile in a terminal with a command).

Comment: Just give it a try in a path without spaces (just make some small test project)

Comment: I must show the line where you include the file.

Comment: #include <sudukutree.h>

Comment: If it's in the same folder as the rest of your project, try `#include "sudukutree.h"` (with quotes)

Comment: Your question refers to `tester.h`. Your comment refers to `<sudukutree.h>`. Which is it? For future reference, it's best to include your actual source code (copy-and-paste it, don't re-type it) in the question.

Comment: we can only help the OP of the OP cooperates by pasting the needed info.  One such needed info is the directory structure between the source code and the include file